# How to have single scale bar in a facet plot of a particular layer in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to have a single scale bar for a faceted plot of point data, where the points refer to geographic coordinate with some data stored in for which facets are created. The problem is when I provide the extent (x.min,x.max,y.min,y.max) the scale bar appears in both facets and defining the 'facet.var' and 'facet.lev' produces an error message. If i define the data instead of extent as (data=df) an irrelevant scale bar appears.

Any help on this would be kindly appreciated.
Thank you!

Here is the reproducible code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(ggsn)

##Data
#pointdata
  type1 <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B")
  lon <- c(75,90,105,75,90,105)
  lat <- c(20,0,30,20,0,30)
  df <- data.frame(lon,lat,type1)

#basemap
  world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")

#plot
  map1 <- ggplot()+
    geom_sf(data=world,color="white",lwd=0.5)+
    coord_sf(xlim = c(70,110), ylim = c(-10,40),expand = T)+
    geom_point(data =df,aes(x = lon, y = lat),
               alpha=1,color="black",shape=21, size=3,stroke=0.3)+
    facet_grid(~type1)+
    scalebar(data=df,location ="topright",dist = 500,dist_unit = "km", transform=T,
             facet.var =c("type1"),facet.lev=c("B"), model = "WGS84", height=0.01,st.size=3)+
    labs(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude")+
    theme_bw()


  map1
```

Comment: You still have undefined variables in your example: ```alpha```, ```col``` and ```ln```. Also, without these, there's a map produced. Can you provide the code that doesn't work for you and/or gives error messages?

Comment: @Sven I have edited it recently. This code produces scalebar but its irrelevant.